# Jar Dependencies and jar clashes using AWS SDK 1.11.105

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk

We are facing some problem regarding jar dependencies and jar clashes while working with AWS java SDK 1.10.105.

We are seeing that in the AWS SDK httpClient 4.5.2 version is used, while we are using 4.5.0 version in our project. It is also coming for httpcore 4.4.4 jar also. What will be the solution? We are not even sure that whether we are facing this error for the jar clashes, we think AWS SDK is independent of all external jars. Please help.

The error we are facing:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients

After using same jar version of AWS SDK, now we are facing this error.We are using jodaTime 2.8.1(Same of SDK)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.auth.internal.AWS4SignerUtils
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.withZoneUTC()Lorg/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter;

Comment: Can you list your maven dependencies or add your pom.xml to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the dependencies:

-

com.fasterxml.jackson

jackson-modified

2.5.4

-

org.apache.commons

commons-csv

1.1

-

commons-logging

commons-logging

1.1.1

-

com.googlecode.json-simple

json-simple

1.1.1

-

log4j

log4j

1.2.16

compile

-

com.fasterxml.jackson.core

jackson-databind

2.6.6

-

com.fasterxml.jackson.core

jackson-databind

2.6.6